# Easy to use Python encryption library/wrapper?

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I want to encrypt an arbitrary-length string with a password in Python. I would prefer *not* to deal with padding, key generation and IVs as I honestly don't know that much about cryptography yet and I'd like to avoid messing up. I'd also prefer using a well-known cypher as AES.

My ideal library (let's call it MagicCrypt) would work like this:

```
from MagicCrypt import AES
p = "plaintext"
k = "password"
crypt = AES(k)
c = crypt.encrypt(p)
p == crypt.decrypt(c) # True
```

I've checked [PyCrypto](http://pycrypto.org), [m2crypto](http://chandlerproject.org/Projects/MeTooCrypto), [pycryptopp](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycryptopp), [GPGme](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/gpgme/index.en.html) and [keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org). Neither of them seem to offer this really easy to use mode. keyczar comes closest, but for some reason wants to use a keyset saved in a file-like object or something similar.

As far as I know I'll have to resort to calling `mcrypt` with Popen, which does offer a mode that works exactly like this - part of the reason I'm guessing there's really no technical reason for this not to exist.

Do you know of an easy to use, secure, crypto library for Python? If not, what's the easiest (yet secure) way of using any of the already mentioned libraries?

Comment: Do you require that the encryption is reversible? i.e. given the password and the encrypted content, do you wish to reconstruct the original string?

Comment: You should write MagicCrypt if you can't find it.

Comment: @GregS really, you think it's better I roll my own wrapper? It's not that I'm lazy, but I'm afraid I'd make a mistake. I have the feeling that there are plenty of gotchas, even when using semi-high-level interfaces like PyCrypto. Wouldn't I be better off just piping to mcrypt?

Comment: @Eduardo Ivanec: Implementing crypto can be full of gotchas, but it is not impossible. Even doing it yourself you would be better off using a high-level library for doing as much of the work as possible. By the way, there is a Java library called [Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/) that aims to do what you want but for Java. It is not going to help you but it proves that it can be done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you list m2crypto, but did you see m2secret?  the example at http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/m2secret/ seems pretty much exactly what you want.

disclaimer: i haven't used it and it's listed on pypi as alpha quality http://pypi.python.org/pypi/m2secret/0.1.1

**update** - some time after answering here i wrote [simple-crypt](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt) which is a simple wrapper for pycrypto.  it does aes encryption for python 2.7 and 3 and is similar to Rob's answer below **but also includes PBKDF2** to generate a more secure key.

Comment: That's great, indeed I missed it and only evaluated m2crypto itself. I'll give it a try! Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576980/

**EDIT**

Modified to use a user-defined password of arbitrary length. Requires pyCrypto. Thrown together in minutes without a test in sight.

**EDIT 2**

Updated version at https://gist.github.com/1192059

Comment: That's neat, but it doesn't seem to support generating a key from a password. If nothing else comes up I'll probably adapt this code and generate the key myself, thanks.

Comment: I see your point. I'm afraid my battery is about to die and I'm not in a position to charge it. I'll get back to you tomorrow (~15hrs).

Comment: That's nice! I'll give it a try too. Thank you.

Comment: I accepted andrew's answer because m2secret is an already existent module closely tied to m2crypto and thus I think closer to what I asked for (a ready-to-use library). Thank you very much for your answer though, I learnt from it.

Answer (score 1):

I think these two packages are currently best suited:
[wheezy.security](http://packages.python.org/wheezy.security/) and [SimpleAES](https://github.com/nvie/SimpleAES). Both have such simple usage documented.

Comment: SimpleAES has a simple interface as requested, but it's only intended for relatively small pieces of text (from its README).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [pyOCB](https://github.com/kravietz/pyOCB):

- pure Python
- no external dependencies
- built-in authentication and encryption in one interface

Sample usage - encryption (and integrity protection):

```
(tag,ciphertext) = ocb.encrypt(plaintext, header)
```

Decryption and authentication:

```
(is_authentic, plaintext2) = ocb.decrypt(header, ciphertext, tag)
```

Lack of integrated message integrity protection seems to be biggest disadvantage of many other packages listed above. I've seen many production applications that were using encrypted block in URL or cookie as "secure" data storage, but could be easily manipulated because of no integrity protecion. And if the only thing you have is "encrypt with AES" library it's unlikely that you'll add HMAC validation yourself.

Comment: It is worth adding that OCB is patented, and the licensing terms are rather complicated.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's complicated at all. If it's open source you don't care. If you're outside of US, you don't care. 

http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/ocb/license.htm

Comment: Patents are often enforced worlwide, so people outside the US definitely care. Besides that, if you develop non-GPL open source, you may want to allow commercial software to use it, and the license will prevent that.