# How do I code a data encryption program using Python?

Tags: python, function, encryption, logic

Once I choose the appropriate encryption algorithm, what function would I use, in Python, to implement it into my security software that I am working on? I can't figure the logic.

Comment: You might want to do some research first.

Comment: https://pynacl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/secret/

Comment: Laurel is right, just look up different encryption algorithms on Wikipedia, then come back with a specific implementation attempt. Maybe start with a simple Caesar cipher. High quality encryption is something you don't write yourself these days, you just use a library.

Comment: https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/ is also worth looking into.

Comment: RC4 encryption is fairly straightforward too, and can take a long-ish key! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4

Comment: I'm surprised nobody's mentioned it yet -- but look into Diffie-Hellman cryptosystems. RSA is a major set of algorithms implementing DH, and the mathematical principles to which it owes its widespread adoption and success are relatively easy to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy to use Python encryption library/wrapper?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296535/easy-to-use-python-encryption-library-wrapper)

Comment: Cryptography is hard to get right and easy to screw up. So the first rule of crypto is "don't do it yourself".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use **PyCrypto**: [https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto.](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto)
It's simple to use:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
>>> message = "The answer is no"
>>> ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
>>> ciphertext
'\xd6\x83\x8dd!VT\x92\xaa`A\x05\xe0\x9b\x8b\xf1'
>>> obj2 = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
>>> obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
'The answer is no'
```

Comment: But that’s unauthenticated and you’re not choosing an IV safely and you’re not demonstrating how to pad the message. Simple to use, hard to get right: the most dangerous combination.

Comment: Awful example of encryption...  If you want to use a string as the key, you should run it through PBKDF2 or similar first.  Additionally, the IV should be generated through cryptographically secure RNG.  If you aren't doing Crypto properly, then you might as well not do it at all.